# Paypal Template D mobile-iframe

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want my paypal TemplateD in my iframe to be mobile friendly.

I asked tech support from paypal this question but they seem to be ignoring me for some reason.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf

if you look at this document at page 45 of the paypal documentation you will see the following:

> templateD
>   - Sets the payment page template to the MiniLayout (iFrame integration) template. When the payment page is viewed from a mobile
>   browser, PayPal will not display a mobile-optimized flow. The reason
>   is that if PayPal automatically displayed a mobile optimized embedded
>   template within a merchant web page that may not be mobile optimized,
>   this can create unexpected and undesira ble results. To display the
>   mobile optmized payment flow, pass either mobile or mobile-iframe in
>   the template HTML variable at transaction time

what exactly means "Pass either mobile or mobile-iframe in the html template variable at transaction time"

I believe i have to create an input of type hidden with the attribute of "value" equal of "mobile-iframe", however i do not know what the value of the "name" attribute is.

i already have a

input  type=hidden name="template" value = "templateD"

I believei need something like this

input type=hidden name="?" value="mobile-iframe"

The Question mark represents that which i do not know.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have probably found the answer to this by now, but I will answer it in case anybody is searching the same answer (like me).

You don't need to send an additional input, you just replace "templateD" with "mobile-iframe".

i.e.

input type="hidden" name="template" value="mobile-iframe"

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The VirtueMart payment method values (configurable and non-configurable parameters such as this one) are stored in table _virtuemart_paymentmethods (id=21 in my VirtueMart 3.0.18 installation) in the field payment_params.

So to change the value for the template html variable, carefully edit this field using phpMyAdmin and change template="templateD" to template="mobile-iframe".